# PHP8.0でWordPressの「Attempt to read property "ID" on null」のエラーを解決したい

Tags: php, wordpress

#### 前提・実現したいこと

PHP7.3からPHP8.0にバージョンアップしたところ、WordPressで以下のエラーメッセージが発生しました。
このエラーを解決したいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
( ! ) Warning: Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /○○○/○○○.php on line ○
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```
<?php $post_id = $post->ID;
```

#### 補足情報

PHP 8.0
WordPress 5.8.2

Comment: [他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿](https://teratail.com/questions/375947) をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

二つあります。

一つ目：これはエラーではありません、警告だけです、もし自分が作ったものではない時に警告は無視しても問題はないと思います。

二つ目：これは単なるヌル問題です、解決するには簡単だと思います、解決方法は主にまた二つ

1. 何らかの確実な内容を入れる：$post_id = 1
2. ヌルの発生もとを見つけてヌルしないようにする

以上

Comment: 該当のソースコードはsidebar.phpに書かれています。404ページでこの警告が発生していて、その他のページでは発生していません。警告文が表に表示されているので無視できないです。404ページで警告文を消すにはどうしたらいいでしょうか…。

Comment: 404ページで該当のソースコードを非表示にすることで解決しました。ありがとうございました！

Comment: 解決できてよかったです。